# how to insert data in subtype table and get key from super type in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

For example got in super type a user:

```
create table Userr
(
    id int primary key identity,
    firstName nvarchar(20),
    lastName nvarchar(20),
    email nvarchar(15) unique not null,
    userName nvarchar(15) unique not null,
    passKey nvarchar(15) not null,
    sex nvarchar(1),
    userType nvarchar(1),
    depID nvarchar(5) ,
)
```

Then in sub-types I got student and instructor :

```
create table Student
(
    stuID int primary key,
    gradYear date ,
    constraint c2 foreign key(stuID) references Userr(id)
)

create table Instructor
(
    insID int primary key,
    salary money ,
    constraint c3 foreign key(insID) references Userr(id)
)
```

All I want is to add new student and new instructor, how can I do this in an efficient way?

Comment: In your topic you seem to focus on a simple "how to" question with a super/sub type design. You then ask about "efficient" but you do not define or explain your focus on that term with respect to inserting a single row. To answer your "topic", you insert a row into Userr first, retrieve the identity value of the inserted row, and then supply it along with the other values for the insert into the desired subtype table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all I want is to add new student and new instructor ,how can I make it in efficient way?

The meaning of `"subtype table"` is not clear, but in order to INSERT new student and new instructor you should use simple INSERT query.

```
INSERT Userr(firstName,lastName,email, userName, passKey)
    VALUES ('Ronen','Ariely', 'NotForYou','pituach','NoWay')
GO
INSERT Student(stuID, gradYear) VALUES (1, '2001-02-27')
GO
```

you had to have the referenced user in the userr table first. This mean that you had to first INSERT the referenced user if it does not exists already.

Comment: thank you for your explanation but for better solution we can remove the 1 from student table and add SCOPE_IDENTITY() for get the ref id from super type